# Dynamically loaded Vue components giving me 404

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

Dynamically loaded Vue components giving me 404 even though the files are compiled correctly into the dist folder by webpack.

Really struggling to see why - but from what i can tell the main.js file is looking  for the files relative to the current URL path that it's in.

Vue loader config

```
module.exports = () => {
  return {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      use: {
          loader: 'vue-loader',
      }
  };
}
```

webpack.congifg

```
module.exports = () => ({
  entry: [
    './entry.js',
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: { 
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'), 'node_modules']
  },
  module: require('./webpack/module')(),
  plugins: require('./webpack/plugins')(),
```

});

The dist output looks like [image: Dist folder outoput]

when the the main.js file is trying to load the files in (1.js, 1.css) it's trying to get them relative to the url path for example

rather then it trying to get them from localhost/dist/1.js it's trying to pull them in relative to the the url i.e localhost/blog/news/1.js.

Comment: Hi there - in order for to let others on the site best help you, could you please post some code? Specifically, your webpack config would be helpful in this case.

Comment: I have updated it now :) - hope it makes a little more sense.